# ECS CannotPullContainerError no space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy my app to AWS ECS  via codepipeline and I see the following error in Codepipline console:

```
Waiting for the task to finishes...

==> The one-off task has failed!!
Container exit code: None
Container exit reason: CannotPullContainerError: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob021600560: no space left on device
Stopped reason: Task failed to start
Container output: None
```

Could someone explain to me how to clear out this space or increase it.

I have logged into the box of both the main app and the worker and ran docker system df.
I see the following:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure where to run the prune command or if I need to do something else.

Comment: Are you using an EC2 or Fargate based Cluster? How large is the Docker Image?

Comment: The image is 980mb in size

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EC2 based cluster :

The Error message you got means there is no enough space left on the host to download the wanted Image.

Which means you need to create some space / increase the disk on the Instance

- For cleaning the current disk you can delete unneeded logs / run `docker system prune`
- For increasing volume size(disk size) - [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I should run the prune command? I logged into my EC2 box but it doesn't look like that is the correct place to run it. 

# docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          2         1         64.41MB   953.6kB (1%)
Containers      1         1         0B        0B
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B